# How to create bastion host in my public vcp using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have vpc with public and private.

How do I create bastion host on the public?

```
module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "~> 2.0"

  name = "${local.name}-vpc"
  cidr = "10.1.0.0/16"

  azs = ["us-east-2a", "us-east-2b", "us-east-2c"]

  private_subnets = ["10.1.1.0/24", "10.1.2.0/24", "10.1.3.0/24"]
  public_subnets  = ["10.1.101.0/24", "10.1.102.0/24", "10.1.103.0/24"]

  single_nat_gateway = true

  enable_nat_gateway   = true
  enable_vpn_gateway   = false
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  public_subnet_tags = {
    Name = "public"
  }

  private_subnet_tags = {
    Name = "private"
  }

  public_route_table_tags = {
      Name = "public-RT"
  }

  private_route_table_tags = {
      Name = "private-RT"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = local.environment
    Name        = local.name
  }
}
```

**Edit**
I add this to the code above:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "bastion-sg" {
  name   = "bastion-security-group"
  vpc_id = "${module.vpc.vpc_id}"

  ingress {
    protocol    = "tcp"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    protocol    = -1
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
  ami                         = "ami-0d5d9d301c853a04a"
  key_name                    = "key"
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids      = ["${aws_security_group.bastion-sg.id}"]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
}
```

But when I run terraform apply I get error:

```
Error: Error launching source instance: InvalidParameter: Security group sg-0e3d05f76119af726 and subnet subnet-4b0c1123 belong to different networks.
        status code: 400, request id: ddce7fc3-3ef9-407d-b0cd-0dda640bb3a9

  on vpc.tf line 108, in resource "aws_instance" "bastion":
 108: resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
```

Comment: `.name` != "an ID"

Comment: also you're not following the docs, if you're trying to do this for a VPC you should use https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#vpc_security_group_ids instead

Comment: I edit my question and change to `id`, but now I get error: InvalidParameter: Security group sg-0e3d05f76119af726 and subnet subnet-4b0c1123 belong to different networks. what do I do wrong?

Comment: That's a different question :)

Comment: ...and you shouldn't edit your question to be something different than what it originally was. If I answered your question, I could have posted the answer. Now it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I want to create bastion host. so I the main question is how to do that. meanwhile I try to find solutions myself and I update my progress. but now I still stuck on this issue and I can't find out why.

Comment: Your issue isn't that you don't understand how to create a bastion. Your issue is that you're not working through the errors as Terraform is giving them to you. The bastion is just an EC2 instance. It's your configuration that's the problem. I showed you the solution to the first error and it landed you on the second error. Try troubleshooting the error that it gives you. The SG and the subnet need to be on the same network. Define your network.

Answer (score 2):

```
  resource "aws_security_group" "bastion-sg" {
  name   = "bastion-security-group"
  vpc_id = "aws_vpc.My_VPC.id"

  ingress {
    protocol    = var.bastion_ingress_protocol
    from_port   = var.bastion_ingress_from_port
    to_port     = var.bastion_ingress_to_port
    cidr_blocks = var.bastion_ingress_cidr
  }

  egress {
    protocol    = var.bastion_egress_protocol
    from_port   = var.bastion_egress_from_port
    to_port     = var.bastion_egress_to_port
    cidr_blocks = var.bastion_egress_cidr
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
  ami                         = var.bastion_ami
  key_name                    = var.key
  instance_type               = var.bastion_instance_type
  security_groups             = [aws_security_group.bastion-sg.id]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
}
```

Comment: Please provide description as well.